# Using generics to cast list of objects

Tags: vb.net, generics

i have some structure that's set by an external library.
It's a list of items, where the itemdata is internaly beeing hold as Object.

When using the list, especially when querying it with linq, i always have to cast the objects.

Here some sample-code:

```
Module Module1

    '========================
    'defined inside the lib
    '========================
    Public Class DataItem
        Public Property P1 As Object
    End Class

    Public Class DataList
        Inherits List(Of DataItem)
    End Class
    '========================


    Public Class D1
        Public Property Val As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim I1 As New D1 With {.Val = "test1"}
        Dim I2 As New D1 With {.Val = "test2"}

        Dim dl As New DataList()
        dl.Add(New DataItem With {.P1 = I1})
        dl.Add(New DataItem With {.P1 = I2})

        Dim ql = (From p In dl Where CType(p.P1, D1).Val = "test1" Select p)

        For Each item In ql
            Console.Out.WriteLine(CType(item.P1, D1).Val)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Is there any way to bypass this casting?
Something like implementing an generic and overloading the DataList and/or DataItem and use my own IEnumerator?
Speed is not an problem, i could touch every object in the list.

Many thanks 
rene

Comment: Why aren't you creating your new objects with the same type as the one defined inside the lib? Or another way to say it: why did you create your custom class `D1` instead of using `DataItem.P1` (I presume that `D1` and `DataItem.P1` are equivalent, since you are casting them with `CType(p.P1, D1)`). The obvious answer would be that if you drop your custom type and use the lib one, you don't need the casting anymore.

Comment: Hi Xavier, the library is doing some heavy processing on the data. e.g. i pass in two different objects and the lib compares them with reflection per property. After the prossecing is done, i have a list of dataitems which i can filter further (e.g. object1 different to object2 or object1 exists, but not object2 etc.). Also the developer who uses the lib must know exactly what he put into the list in order to process it afterwards. 
I can do smal changes on the lib (i have the code) and of course on my code.
If it was all my Code, i would change the lib to use generics by default...